# Google Pub/Sub Emulator - Publishing message using Java's HTTP.POST throws 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the Google Pub/Sub emulator running locally on my machine. I am able to publish a message using YARC (Yet Another REST Client) with the following details:

URL:
`POST http://localhost:8311/v1/projects/my-project/topics/my-project-test:publish`

Payload:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "1": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This results in a 200 response, and I can see in the console output from the emulator that the messages are received.

Now, when I try to do the same using Java's HTTP library, I am consistently getting 400 errors. Here's the code:

```
String payload = "{\"messages\":[{\"attributes\":{\"1\":1}}]}";

HTTP.Response response = HTTP.POST(options.getPubsubRootUrl() + "/v1/projects/my-project/topics/my-project-test:publish", payload);
```

I checked the headers in the debugger and found that they are:

`Content-Type: application/json`

`Content-length: ####(some number)`

I'm sending `Content-Type` from the REST client as well (`Content-length` may be being sent behind the scenes as well)

As far as I can tell these requests are identical, but for some reason doing it from my Java code is causing an error while doing it from a REST client is not.

Is there anything glaring here I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please specify what is this HTTP class? For me it does not seem to be part of standard Java.

Comment: @BalázsNemes Oh wow, it's always the simplest thing... I copied that line from elsewhere in the code and it was actually `org.neo4j.test.server.HTTP` - auto-imported when I pasted in Eclipse. Changed to Unirest and it works - thanks! Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Cool, actually I havn't used any of them, but will try Unirest when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the HTTP class I thought was a standard Java class was `org.neo4j.test.server.HTTP`, which was auto-imported in Eclipse when I copied that line from elsewhere in my code.

That particular implementation is, I believe, designed to work with a neo4j test server and must do something beyond simple HTTP requests (add some headers or something), resulting in the requests being somehow different than what I was sending from YARC.